# Splitting Audio File

Tags: objective-c, audio, split, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer for recording and Playing an Audio. I want to insert an Audio in the AVAudioPlayer with the Specific time by placing the marker. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    -(void)Play
{
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[FileDetailsRec valueForKey:@"Path"]] error:nil];
    [avPlayer setCurrentTime:5.01f];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];
    objTimer = [NSTimer  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.07f target:self selector:@selector(stop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)stop
{ 
    [objTimer invalidate];
    [avPlayer stop];
}
```

Please check this once.... i hope,it help you..

https://documentation.apple.com/en/soundtrackpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=6%26section=18%26tasks=true

Comment: I wants to split the main audio and insert an new audio.